How to get number of a specifc row php
/$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_cad WHERE name like '$src_names%' ORDER BY id ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Id | name
------------
1     James
2     Claus  
7     John
10    Maria
21    Sonia
22    Evelin

How do I get the result with the specific line number?
4-Maria
A form and function explanation.Thank you in advance

Is the table example the whole table or the query result?

you can use where id=4 at the end of the query

The result, Line 4, how to get a number for row... Id 10 name Maria is row 4... How to get a number of specific row on tb

Rakesh Rebbavarapu id is 10, i need print a specifc row number... On case is 4

i have updated the answer can u please check

Database rows are not numbered. The output order+index depends on your query, especially on order and limit.

"I need to print a specifc row number" Why? What is the real problem that you are trying to solve?

@Olivier, In my case it would be the order of registration of several registered studies, But rejected registrations are deleted, generating skipped IDs. When the operator is going to perform the tests on a given set of studies, they need to be done in order. But when filtering 1 result the number should be the same as when there is no filter.  Like a excel document with enumerated lines. But is solved.

@Wiimm Exactly, but I need to enumerate, and keep the row number in order when filtered. When I search for a row I have to know its position in the table. Like row 97, not id 143 go 207 go blah blah... I need real position ordered by registry order

Relevant reading: MySQL get row position in ORDER BY and PHP MYSQL finding row number/rank from table with order by clause and MySQL: How to get a sequential number with rows? and how to get the position of sorted rows using mysql and php

You can use the ROW_NUMBER function:
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, name FROM tb_cad
WHERE name like '$src_names%' ORDER BY id ASC;

If the result you want is to find Maria's row numbers in the entire table, you need to query twice:
SELECT id, name FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, name FROM tb_cad ORDER BY id ASC
) tmp 
WHERE name like '$src_names%';


Result of search is the same 1-Maria, not 4-Maria... Maria is at row 4

You confirmed in the comment above that the table in the question is the result of the query. If you are not mistaken, the result should have 6 rows and Maria's row number should be 4. If you see a result of 1-Maria, it means that your query result only has 1 row.

Thanks in advance. No, my question is how to find the line number where Maria is. In the case above, Maria is on line 4, but her id is 10. But if you know another way, I'd be grateful.

Now it works perfectly, with an improvement in filtering compared to the solution presented below. Thanks.

SET @row_number := 0;

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number+1) AS line_number, id, name 
    FROM tb_cad 
    WHERE name LIKE '$src_names%' 
    ORDER BY id ASC
) AS numbered_result
WHERE line_number = 4;

-The @row_number variable will increment for each row, assigning a line number.
-The query filters the result for the 4th line, where line_number = 4.
the return query will be this
line_number | id  | name
4           | 10  | Maria

I'm assuming id and name are the column names in the database table.
$sql_all = "SELECT id FROM tb_cad ORDER BY id ASC";
$result_all = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_all);

$record_positions = [];
$line_number = 1;

while ($row_all = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_all)) {
    $record_positions[$row_all['id']] = $line_number;
    $line_number++;
}

$sql_filter = "SELECT * FROM tb_cad WHERE name LIKE '$src_names%' ORDER BY id ASC";
$result_filter = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_filter);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_filter)) {
    $line_number = $record_positions[$row['id']];
    echo "Line Number: " . $line_number . " - Name: " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
}




I need to get a position row number on tb... Id -10 - Maria is at row 4

Result of search is 1 Maria not 4

Not an optimal solution but this should work

Like a charm, works perfect now.

Thanks for solution, Is it possible to improve this function with a multiquery?When you have time and can review, I would appreciate it. I would love an explanation too. For now I'll use it like this

@Erasmo Sure, i'm a bit busy now. i'll try to get a optimal solutions by end of the day. Note: You might see performance degrade in the large database with millions records with the above solution

I understand and appreciate it, I'll mark Shingo's answer above for now, since in this case it worked faster.My DB has approximately 35k rows and using the multi query above was better for filtering. However, your solution also works well. Thanks again.
